# calling a function does not work

Tags: c

My program is using stacks to input and output points.
My problem is when I want to output the points in the main function.
Like this it works fine:

```
push(readPoint());
printStackElement(pop());
```

But if I want to call the functions step by step I don`t get the points.
Why is pop() not returning the firstStackPoint.p, or what do I have to do so that it works?

```
//file: pointstack.h 

#ifndef POINTSTACK_H
#define POINTSTACK_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point
{
    float rX;
    float rY;
    float rZ;
};
typedef struct point POINT;

struct stackPoint
{
    POINT p;
    struct stackPoint *next;
};
typedef struct stackPoint STACK_POINT;
typedef STACK_POINT *STACK_POINT_PTR;


void push(POINT pushPoint);
POINT pop();
int isEmpty();
void printStackElement(POINT aPoint);

#endif


//file: pointstack.c

#include "pointstack.h" 

STACK_POINT_PTR stackTop = NULL;

void push(POINT pushPoint){
     STACK_POINT_PTR stackPoint = (STACK_POINT_PTR) malloc(sizeof(STACK_POINT));

    if(stackPoint == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error... End\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    stackPoint->p = pushPoint;
    stackPoint->next = stackTop;
    stackTop = stackPoint;

    return;
}

POINT pop(){
    STACK_POINT firstStackPoint = *stackTop;

    free(stackTop);

    stackTop = firstStackPoint.next;

    return firstStackPoint.p;
}

int isEmpty(){    
    if(stackTop == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void printStackElement(POINT aPoint)
{
    printf("Point x: %f, Point y: %f, Point z: %f \n", aPoint.rX, aPoint.rY, aPoint.rZ);
    return;
}


//file: stackmain.c

#include "pointstack.h"

int main(void){

POINT readPoint() 
{
    POINT userPoint;

    printf("enter x value\n");
    scanf("%62f", &userPoint.rX);
    printf("enter y value\n");
    scanf("%62f", &userPoint.rY);
    printf("enter z value\n");
    scanf("%62f", &userPoint.rZ);

    return userPoint;
}

    POINT userPoint; 
    char choice;
    POINT aPoint;
    POINT bPoint;
    STACK_POINT firstStackPoint;


    printf("p add point, q output: \n");

    while(1)
    {
    scanf("%c", &choice);

        if(choice == 'p') 
        {
            readPoint();
            aPoint = userPoint;
            push(aPoint);

            printf("p add point, q output: \n");       
        }

        if(choice == 'q')
        {
            while(!isEmpty()){

                pop();
                bPoint = firstStackPoint.p;
                printStackElement(bPoint);

            }
            break;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you define the `readPoint()` function inside main intentionally?

Comment: After you fix your other issues, the body of your entire `while (!isEmpty())` loop can, and should, be replaced with `printStackElement(pop());` Neither `bPoint` nor `firstStackPoint` are needed in `main()` at all (and the latter was pointless to begin with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `userPoint` and never initializing it and then trying to assign it to `aPoint`., change this

```
readPoint();
```

to

```
aPoint = readPoint();
```

and take the definition of `readPoint()` outside of `main()`, that is not valid in standard c.

Also, you don't need `userPoint` declared in `main()` you don't ever use it, since apparently you are using `gcc` I would suggets to compile like this

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow
```

that way you can prevent a lot of silly things that sometimes are not easy to see.

And use

```
getchar();
```

instead of

```
system("pause");
```

it's os specific.